# Frama-C acsl max example from manual not working

Tags: frama-c, alt-ergo

I believe I am missing something obvious, but I have tried a lot and I haven't managed to find the source of the problem.

I am following the acsl [guide](https://frama-c.com/acsl_tutorial_index.html) from Frama-C.
There is this introductory example of how to verify the correctness of finding the maximum value in an array:

```
/*@ requires n > 0;
    requires \valid(p+ (0 .. n-1));
    ensures \forall int i; 0 <= i <= n-1 ==> \result >= p[i];
    ensures \exists int e; 0 <= e <= n-1 && \result == p[e];
*/
int max_seq(int* p, int n) {
  int res = *p;
  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (res < *p) { res = *p; }
    p++;
  }
  return res;
}
```

However, running `frama-c -wp -wp-prover alt-ergo samenum.c -then -report` I get:

```
[wp] Warning: Missing RTE guards
[wp] samenum.c:8: Warning: Missing assigns clause (assigns 'everything' instead)
[wp] 2 goals scheduled
[wp] [Alt-Ergo] Goal typed_max_seq_ensures_2 : Timeout (Qed:1ms) (10s)
[wp] [Alt-Ergo] Goal typed_max_seq_ensures : Timeout (Qed:2ms) (10s)
[wp] Proved goals:    0 / 2
  Alt-Ergo:        0  (interrupted: 2)
[report] Computing properties status...

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--- Properties of Function 'max_seq'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

[    -    ] Post-condition (file samenum.c, line 3)
            tried with Wp.typed.
[    -    ] Post-condition (file samenum.c, line 4)
            tried with Wp.typed.
[    -    ] Default behavior
            tried with Frama-C kernel.
```

It seems that alt-ergo times out before proving the property. For what is worth, I tried with higher time-out but it still doesn't work.

I am using:

- frama-c: 19.1
- why3: 1.2.0
- alt-ergo: 2.3.2

I am running this on Ubuntu 18.04 and before running the command I run: `why3 config --detect` to make sure why3 knows about alt-ergo.

Any ideas? Can anyone verify that this is example is not working?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This mini-tutorial was written quite a long time ago and is not really up to date. A new version of the website should appear in the upcoming months. Basically, this contract, as well as the invariant for the loop pointed by @iguerNL were meant to be verified using the Jessie plugin, and not the WP plugin of Frama-C. Among the differences between these two plugins, Jessie did not need `assigns` clauses for loops and functions, while WP needs them.

Thus, a complete annotated `max_seq` function could be this one:

```
/*@ requires n > 0; 
    requires \valid(p+ (0..n−1));
    assigns \nothing;
    ensures \forall int i; 0 <= i <= n−1 ==> \result >= p[i]; 
    ensures \exists int e; 0 <= e <= n−1 && \result == p[e]; 
*/ 
int max_seq(int* p, int n) { 
  int res = *p; 
  //@ ghost int e = 0; 
  /*@ loop invariant \forall integer j; 0 <= j < i ==> res >= \at(p[j],Pre); 
      loop invariant \valid(\at(p,Pre)+e) && \at(p,Pre)[e] == res; 
      loop invariant 0<=i<=n; 
      loop invariant p==\at(p,Pre)+i; 
      loop invariant 0<=e<n; 
      loop assigns i, res, p, e;
      loop variant n-i;
  */ 
  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) { 
    if (res < *p) { 
      res = *p; 
      //@ ghost e = i; 
    }
    p++; 
  } 
  return res; 
}
```

where we specify that the functions does not assign anything in memory, and that the loop assigns the different local variables `i`, `res`, `p` and `e` (thus leaving `n` unchanged).

Note that more recent tutorials are available to learn about the use of Frama-C with the WP plugin. The future version of the Frama-C website mentions:

- [A comprehensive tutorial on ACSL and WP](https://allan-blanchard.fr/frama-c-wp-tutorial.html)
- [Another tutorial, with specifications inspired notably from C++ containers](https://github.com/fraunhoferfokus/acsl-by-example)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Your code snippet works just fine. Two small comments: (i) the new version with the WP plugin seems much more complicated, so why the change? (ii) it is misleading that the official website has wrong documentation, I really hope that it will get updated it soon.

Comment: Just to be clear, because maybe it was not, loop invariant annotations are necessary for both WP and Jessie. The only difference is the fact that WP always needs the assigns annotation.
In fact in the general case, the assigned memory locations are not that easy to infer and can result in complex proof obligations that are hard to handle by automated solvers. Thus, here, Jessie does not need assigns annotation but if the example was more complex, it could. WP is somewhat more homogeneous by always requiring them.

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot to add invariants for the "for" loop. See Section "10.2 Loop Invariants" in the manual you gave (https://frama-c.com/acsl_tutorial_index.html)

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but even with invariants it doesn't work. Could you provide a full working example for max_seq?